# string comparison in php

Tags: php, html, string

I am trying to compare two strings I get from a password form in HTML.

They are being stored in variables from `$_POST`. I print them out and they look the same, but the code below will never evaluate to true, only false. Why does that happen?

```
//Verify the passwords match
if( ($passwd != $pass_confirm) && ($new_email != $email_confirm) ){
    echo "Email and/or password do not match";
    return FALSE;
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If this is part of a function (the return statement indicates this), then don't forget to return `true` as well. Then as others already answered, use an **or** instead of **and**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your code to show the error message, both the email and password must be wrong.

Try using `||` instead of `&&`, so the error is shown when just one of them is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I also fixed my code to use strcmp, which seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you print them out and they look the same, you might have a trailing newline character problem. Perhaps you could try **[trimming](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)** the strings before comparison? Doing a **[var_dump](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)** might help to pinpoint the problem because it shows the length of the string.

Also, I would suggest the following check (note the `||` and strict comparison operators):

```
if ($passwd !== $pass_confirm || $new_email !== $email_confirm) {
    echo "Email and/or password do not match";
    return false;
}
```